# How to use shp2pgsql

Tags: postgis

My question should be very simple to answer for anyone not being a self-taught newbie like me...

On this page is a cheatsheet concerning a function to be used in GIS/DB environnement : http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg

I would like to create a script allowing users to just have to click on it to launch the process, given the proper datas. But I don't understand how to use this. It obviously doesn't work in a Python console, nor directly in the windows console. How is it supposed to work ? What language is this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shp2pgsql is indeed a command line tool. It comes with your PostgreSQL/PostGIS installation (usually) and, if not accessible via PATH-variable, can (usually) be run from within the /bin-folder in your PostgreSQL-Installation. You can also always 'make' the programm from source in any location yourself, if needed.

EDIT:

One way to set up a script (independent of whether you use it within qgis own python environment or not) would be to use Pythons [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) (or os.system) module (check related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392466/python-scripts-to-ingest-a-shapefile-into-a-postgresql-postgis-database-utilizin)) to write to shell and execute shp2pgsql.

A slightly more sophisitcated solution to (batch) insert (multiple) shapefiles via script could be to implement ogr2ogr via gdal/ogr module within python (check [this](http://www.naturalgis.pt/blog/2015/02/27/a-new-qgis-tool-based-on-ogr2ogr-to-import-vectors-in-postgis/) blog). That, however, would require a working installation of the [gdal core library](http://www.gdal.org/), and the respective Python bindings (at least to use outside of QGIS Python environment, where it is pre-installed AFAIK), which can be tiresome at times. Once installed correctly, it offers a powerful (I dare say almighty) toolset for geodata management and manipulation via Python, though.

Apart from that, the [blog](http://www.naturalgis.pt/blog/2015/02/27/a-new-qgis-tool-based-on-ogr2ogr-to-import-vectors-in-postgis/) link I provided also states the implementation of a batch insert script/tool (which operates ogr2ogr) in qgis 2.8 toolbox...maybe that can help you, either with your work directly or (via [sourcecode](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/97e796906f21f5e4ae5f750593e5ce5ddce028c3)) to point you in the direction of creating your own tool.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And would you have any clue on how I could create a plugin, potentially accessible from inside QGIS, programmed in Python, and most importantly (here comes my question) how to call shp2pgsql from within a Python script ?